# Using clearTimeout(x) in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am writing codes where the code will do some polling for statistics to the server using AJAX. My web application is getting data from the server every 3 seconds once the server returned the data. It is working good but however, I want to apply clearTimeout(x) function to stop the execution and print something to user when any error occur like "timeout" or "error" triggered by `error` setting. I managed to search the similar case with me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350746/using-settimeout-with-ajax-calls) and this also [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380219/how-can-i-stop-this-settimeout-function-from-running). But for some reason my code does not do what I want. Here is what I have so far

```
var timeoutid = 0;

var myfunc = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pull.php",
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            if( status==="timeout" || status==="error") {
                alert("Timeout or unable to receive statistics!");
                clearTimeout(timeoutid);
            }
        },
        success: function(msg){ 
            $('#res').val(msg);
            //timeoutid = setTimeout(poll, 3000);
        },
        complete: function(){
            timeoutid = setTimeout(myfunc, 3000);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
}

myfunc();
```

The result of the above when I disable my Internet adapter is it keeps looping and alert me the error without stopping the execution. I don't really know how or where do I put my clearTimeout due to **localized variable** issue based on what I have read. Not really a master in jQuery in detailed though. Appreciate your kind respond and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are again creating a new timer in the complete callback which will get executed in the case of error also

```
var myfunc = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pull.php",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if (status === "timeout" || status === "error") {
                alert("Timeout or unable to receive statistics!");
            }
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#res').val(msg);
        },
        complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
            if (status !== "timeout" && status !== "error") {
                setTimeout(myfunc, 3000);
            }
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });
}

myfunc();
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tested it and it works! That explains it. Great, but do I have to use clearTimeout(x) function?

Comment: @UserProg not required.. if you were using an interval, then you would have to... since you hare using timeout there is no need to

Comment: Noted on that. Because I am a bit confused on `setInterval` and `setTimeout`. Anyway thank you for your help. I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Hi There, one question. It is working OK. However sometimes & I don't even know why when I click the link to the same page containing the above script or navigate to other page, the alert in the `error:` call back will be popped up. Any idea why?

Comment: @UserProg see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370322/jquery-ajax-fires-error-callback-on-window-unload-how-do-i-filter-out-unload-a & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699941/handle-ajax-error-when-a-user-clicks-refresh